# Hair transplant for baldness

Tags: hairloss, alopecia, hair-transplant

I am 24 I am getting very low density in my hair .. I tried min oxidil and finasteride and all .. I am genetically have that baldness history . can I prevnt my baldness or can I do hair transplant ? And will it be permanent solution ?