# Is hair transplantation really efficient

Tags: surgery, treatment-options, hair-transplant, hairloss

Men hair loss is a real issue, and having been suffered from it trying to apply various inefficient ways, the only final way to resolve the issue, I believe, is hair transplantation. However, I'm not really sure if it's really a way to go. Trying to google for a good read on hair transplantation, I mostly get ads and ad-like articles that promise wonderful results, but I can't trust ads before I get a solid picture. The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hair_transplantation) seems to have multiple issues, and it's not really easy to read a medical article being not a native speaker (as I'm from the Eastern Europe).

Is it really true that hair transplantation works and are there real examples of public men that applied this kind of surgery?

(Offhand, I can remember Elton John and Wayne Rooney only, but I'm still interested the way their results are really achieved. The way the question is asked may appear to be more appropriate for the Skeptics StackExchange site, but I think that the health area is closer to it. This one may also look like [Hair transplant for baldness](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/1885/hair-transplant-for-baldness) but that one seems be slightly different. If any issue, please move, close or delete. Thank you.)